# Can this difference operator be factorised?

Tags: calculus

If a difference operator is defined as $$LY_i=\left(-\epsilon\dfrac{D^+ -D^-}{h_1}+aD^-\right)Y_i,\quad 1\leq i\leq N$$ Suppose $Y_N$ and $Y_0$ are given and that the difference operators are defined as follows $D^+V_i=(V_{i+1}-V_i)/h_1$, $D^-V_i=(V_i-V_{i-1})/h_1$. How is it possible to write the difference operator as $$LY_i=(Y_N-Y_0)\left(-\epsilon\dfrac{D^+ -D^-}{h_1}+aD^-\right)\psi_i?$$

I am thinking that [telescoping trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) is used, but am failing to see how.

If my question is not clear could someone clarify the second $L_\epsilon^NY_i$ on page 57 of the excerpt which is attached below.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Look at the edits if you want to know how to get the larger parentheses.

Comment: @MTurgeon, thanks. There also seem to be a problem with the fraction line.

Comment: How is $\psi_i$ defined?

Comment: @DoctorDan, it's a function in terms of $a,\epsilon, h_1$. You could check the link I just added.

Comment: Could you paste the excerpt from the book?

Comment: @DoctorDan, it's pdf how do I do that?

Comment: [This link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85516/embed-image-in-stackoverflow) should help you include an image.

Comment: @DoctorDan, thanks I have now put the images.

Answer (score 0):

$-\frac{\epsilon}{h^2} (Y_{i+1}-2Y_i + Y_{i-1}) + \alpha(Y_i-Y_{i-1}) = 0 \;\;\; (1)$

$-\frac{\epsilon}{h^2} Y_{N+1} + \left ( \frac{2\epsilon}{h^2} + \alpha \right )Y_N - \left ( \frac{\epsilon}{h^2} + \alpha \right ) Y_{N-1} = 0$

$\dots$

$Y_{N} = \frac{\epsilon Y_{N+1}}{2\epsilon + \alpha h^2}+\frac{\epsilon + \alpha h^2}{2\epsilon + \alpha h^2} Y_{N} \equiv aY_{N+1} + (1-a)Y_{N-1} = aY_{N+1}(1+(1-a) + (1-a)^2 + \dots+ (1-a)^N)+(1-a)^{N+1}Y_0 = a\frac{1-(1-a)^{N+1}}{a}Y_{N+1} +(1-a)^{N+1}Y_0 = (1-(1-a)^{N+1})Y_{N+1}+(1-a)^{N+1}Y_0$

$Y_{N-1} = (1-(1-a)^{N})Y_{N+1}+(1-a)^{N}Y_0$

Hence, (1) can be rewritten as a function of $Y_0$ and $Y_{N+1}$. Collecting the terms by $Y_0$ and $Y_{N+1}$ and defining your $\phi$ appropriately, you should get the desired.

Not worth the bounty but should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I am actually trying to follow Lemma 7.1.

Comment: Since the $L_{\epsilon}^N Y_i = 0$ holds for all $i \in 1,2,...,N-1$, every such $Y_i$ can be expressed in terms of $Y_{i+1}$ and $Y_{i-1}$. Starting with $Y_{N}$, express $Y_i$ this way until only $Y_N$ and $Y_0$ are left. You should get the desired.

Comment: could you please elaborate I am stuck here.